# Rails: redirect_to external url(google maps) and pass params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a feature in my rails app where I want to redirect to the google directions url (https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1) and get directions from the current location to the destination. I'm trying to implement this according to the google maps API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action). Unfortunately this is not working, it does redirect to the google url but it doesn't pass the params in order to setup the directions properly.

This is the setup I have:

the link to along with the params that google requires in order for this to work:

```
<%= link_to 'Directions', initialize_path(:origin => @origin, :destination => @destination), method: :get %>
```

the route:

```
get 'initialize' => 'pages#initialize', :as => 'initialize'
```

the method redirecting to the google url and passing the required params as well:

```
def initialize
  redirect_to generate_url('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1',
                         { :origin=> params[:origin], :destination => params[:destination] })
end
```

the helper:

```
def generate_url(url, parameters ={})
  uri = URI(url)
  uri.query = parameters.to_query
  uri.to_s
end
```

The console shows that params are not nil and they actually are passing:

```
`Started GET "/initialize?    destination=40.712775%2C-74.005973&origin=40.720341%2C-74.044847" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-21 17:53:55 +0200
Processing by PagesController#initialize as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"50liTLXVpXgGcLxEzFHRMZ0FNQ5eyvoAY8+qSb6LJ549BitH1Li91QcnKWggoQbzrdPrEDrotT2pVvEiDdiTAg==", "destination"=>"40.712775, -74.005973", "origin"=>"40.720341,-74.044847"}
Redirected to https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?destination=40.712775%2C-74.005973&origin=40.720341%2C-74.044847
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a more simple approach to this:

`<%= link_to "Directions", ('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1''&origin='+@origin+'&destination='+@destination) %>`